# Thrown exception details

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

When my application fails, a `catch` block shows a messageBox with the exception stack trace, so that I could easily see the number of line that fails.
The `try` block includes the main method which invokes the others.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    DetailsTextBox.Text = e.StackTrace;
}
```

Sometimes, a method from another class (not the main) fails.
Since I would like to show the same messageBox, from the catch block there I throw the exception to the main class:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw (ex);
}
```

My problem:
Now the line number shown by the stack trace is the line from which I **throw** the exception, not the line where the application **fails**.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should just use `throw` not `throw (ex)` as that will lose the stack trace.

Comment: Or, better, don't catch exceptions that you're not going to handle.

Comment: @DanielKelley. Thanks. That's it! Post it as an answer so that I could get it as the selected one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just use `throw` not `throw (ex)` as that will lose the stack trace.

However, as John Saunders pointed out you might be better of not catching the exception in the first place, although there are certain scenarios where this can be useful.

Comment: Didn't understand why I cannot throw the exception, so that a class, which has access to a custom form I've created to show the exception details, uses this form to show the details.  The class which throws the exception to the main class can't use this form I mentioned for some reason, as problematic duplicate relation. Make sense? Thanks again.